# associate user account with an email on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, email, user-management

Can I associate an email with a user on linux?
such that I can easily send email etc to specific users from certain cronjobs.

I have cron up and running, I have a mailserver up and running,
I just need an easy way of extracting mailadr for a user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just create the associations in `/etc/aliases` and address the emails to their local username.